# Espacios en ScrollView en AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, scroll, scroll-view

Tengo una duda, estoy implementando un `ScrollView` en mi actividad, pero esta misma añade unos gigantes espacios en la interfaz antes y después de cada elemento que añado. Dejo un **GIF** demostrativo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el `layout` de mi `activity`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Actividades.MisBuilds"
    android:background="@color/black">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">
            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                android:id="@+id/banerMisBuilds"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                app:adSize="BANNER"
                app:adUnitId="asdadsaadd">
            </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/logo_gi"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <TextView
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/sadness"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:text="Selecciona un personaje:"/>
            <Spinner
                android:background="@color/black"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/spPJMisBuilds"/>
            <ScrollView
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <com.frabasoft.genshinimpactrecursos.TouchImage.TouchImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imgPJMisBuilds"
                        android:src="@drawable/wallpaper"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    </com.frabasoft.genshinimpactrecursos.TouchImage.TouchImageView>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="60dp"
                            android:layout_height="250dp">
                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:background="@drawable/ig_logo"
                                android:layout_width="50dp"
                                android:layout_height="50dp"/>
                        </LinearLayout>
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="250dp"
                            android:orientation="vertical">
                            <EditText
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="50dp"
                                android:hint="Stat Principal"
                                android:textColorHint="@color/white"/>
                            <EditText
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="50dp"
                                android:hint="Stat Secundario A"
                                android:textColorHint="@color/white"/>
                            <EditText
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="50dp"
                                android:hint="Stat Secundario B"
                                android:textColorHint="@color/white"/>
                            <EditText
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="50dp"
                                android:hint="Stat Secundario C"
                                android:textColorHint="@color/white"/>
                            <EditText
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="50dp"
                                android:hint="Stat Secundario D"
                                android:textColorHint="@color/white"/>
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

¿Alguien me dice por qué se me crean esos espacios y cómo los quito?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres que todos tus vistas se muevan al deslizar excepto tu `AdView`, deberías hacer lo siguiente:

```
<LinearLayout
   ...
   <AdView ... />
   <ScrollView 
      ...> 
      <LinearLayout

      <!-- todas tus vistas aquí -->

      </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

También fíjate como usas tu `android:layout_height` en tus vistas. Si usas `android:layout_height="match_parent"` va a tener el tamaño del parent que en tu caso sería toda la pantalla. También puedes usar `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`, pero esto depende de tu diseño.

Comment: No, como se ve en el código, solo me interesa que se mueva lo que está dentro del `ScrollView`. Además, he intercambiado las propiedades del mismo (`match_parent` por `wrap_content`) antes de realizar la pregunta.

Comment: Vale, creo que he encontrado una solución. Lo que puedes hacer es usar un tamaño fijo para tu `TouchImageView`. Algo como lo siguiente: `android:layout_height="480dp"`  El height obviamente depende del tamaño de tu imagen.